# How to fake submit with a button outside the form

Tags: css, html, forms

I want to have a top menu with New, Save, Cancel buttons and below, 3 different entry forms, similar to a "desktop application". When form1 is filled up, Save button would submit the form. Also, if form2 or form3 are filled up, the same Save button can submit the form, taking into account that is in a different form.

Is it possible to do this, a submit button outside form tags ?
If not, any suggestion how to fake submit?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not same form (for all three of them) ? Could you post some code please ?

Comment: maybe, you should use javascript to post form data

Comment: This sounds unnecessarily tricky. It is not good for usability (or accessibility) to have a button that acts on different forms depending on previous actions. What do you expect to gain, as opposite to having separate buttons inside each form?

Comment: At the beginning I thought on different forms because 1 form is for customers, another for product and other for orders. But Imane may have a point about single form because it seems I would have to gather info from different input elements and then submit. I know it´s more complicated but looks more like the desktop application we try to replace.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to trigger the submit event with .submit in jQuery by example.

Here is the doc : http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an `<input type="submit">` button or jQuery call you could use the new HTML5 `<button>` element and its `form` attribute to specify which form(s) the button belongs to. Then just set its `formaction` attribute to the required destination. [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Example:

```
<form id="form1">
    ...
</form>
<form id="form2">
    ...
</form>
<form id="form3">
    ...
</form>
<button form="form1 form2 form3" formaction="processForm.php" formmethod="POST">
    Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 $("#formId").submit(function() { /*your stuff*/ });
```

Comment: The pleasure is all mine! Please consider accepting the right answer from these. Thanx!